# Highest weight representations of Kac—Moody algebras: what is inside the weight spaces?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras

Let $V(\lambda)$ be the unique irreducible representation of a Kac—Moody algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with the highest weight $\lambda$. If $\mathfrak{g}$ is not of finite type, then even for $\lambda$ one of the fundamental weights the weights of $V(\lambda)$ usually have multiplicities $\geqslant2$.

> Is there a nice way to pick a basis in each of the weight spaces $V(\lambda)_\mu$?

Here "nice" means that there is an explicit description of the action of the standard generators of $\mathfrak{g}$, so one could actually write (infinite) matrices for the Lie algebra elements. I have checked some sources including *Lie Algebras of Finite and Affine Type* by R. Carter and *Affine Lie Algebras, Weight Multiplicities and Branching Rules* by Kass, Moody, Patera and Slansky, but none contains such details even for the smallest cases like $\tilde{A}_1$. Here is a picture from the second:

[image]

As you can see, this diagram gives no hint to how exactly the generators act inside the weight spaces. I guess this can be reconstructed from the desription of $V(\lambda)$ as a quotient of the Verma module, but this seems quite computationaly extensive, so I was wondering whether someone has already done it in some cases (say, for the untwisted affine KM algebras for some particular choice of $\lambda$)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key word you're looking for is **Littelmann path model**, which gives a nice geometric description for the basis of a weight space of a highest-weight representation of a symmetrisable Kac-Moody algebra (see e.g. http://people.bath.ac.uk/lpah20/GeomSemNP.pdf for an introduction), and gives a fairly explicit algebraic description of this basis (see http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~littelma/montreal.pdf Theorem 5.2), from which it is possible to calculate the action of the standard generators.

While I don't know of a precise reference where this is written up, it is a good exercise to calculate these things for, say, $\tilde A_1$ and $\tilde A_2$.

Comment: The first link is broken.